# Erasing a cycle leaves a graph connected

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a connected simple graph $G=\left(V,E\right)$ such that $\mathrm{deg}(v_i)\geq 3$ for all $v_i \in V$. Prove that there exists a cycle which when we delete, the graph remains connected.